# Audit log of processes

Tags: linux, redhat, anti-virus, process

I was wondering if there is a way that I can check to see the times a certain process ran. I'm running RedHat.

Thanks.

Comment: As in a cron or the length/since when a process is being run?

Comment: How does your `[antivirus]` tag relate to your question?

Comment: @Dennis, the server admins unnecessarily have x11 and Symantec installed on a webserver. We've had issues with the scanner causing unnecessary server load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, depending on whether or not your mystery process was configured to use syslog, you could check `/var/log/messages`.

Answer (score 2):

Is [process accounting](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/en/man8/sa.8.html)  [installed](http://shibuvarkala.blogspot.com/2009/04/howto-enable-process-accounting-in.html)?

Answer (score 1):

Look for lastcomm and auditd, but they're only good if you had them installed first.